# How can I up vote a single user to get them in the review queue quicker?

Tags: discussion, voting, up-votes

So this is what I wanted to do:

> Since there are almost always around 200 posts in the `Close Vote` review queue, and the system doesn't have enough active users with 3k+ rep, so I thought why don't I up vote some users (I don't know them personally) who are:
>
> 1. Active in the review process.
> 2. Close enough to 3k rep.

So I did just that! Of course, while doing so, I made sure that the up voted questions / answers of the user actually deserves the up votes.

Of course, I didn't know about [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/serial-voting-reversed) until today!

> When a single user continually votes (up or down) on many of your posts within a short period of time, the system considers these votes to be invalid and removes them.

Ah! Now I feel bad for that user.

[image: facepalm]

<sub>[facepalm]</sub>

> Note: I've done it more than once, but only got the hammer by the system this time, probably because I did this in a shorter period this time (silly me!). I thought I can vote whoever I want (with responsibility of course).

To be honest, I still want to do that, but in a way that is allowed in the system. Because:

1. Not many people vote in WPSE.
2. Not many people participate in the review process.

So my question is:

> How can I *(if at all)* expedite the process of one or more people becoming the part of the review queue? Or does it have to be all 100% natural?

**Foot Note:**

<sub>OK, let's say the correct answer is *I shouldn't do that*. In that case, may I ask you good folks to join in the voting system more please? That way this same process I tried to do all by myself will happen naturally.</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, thanks for informing us.

You didn't do something wrong if you didn't know how the system works, Could happen to everyone. Now that you know, you shouldn't do it again. The system will can detect such behavior and a mod may find it suspicious, maybe enforcing a suspension on your account if it continues. You can read more about serial voting [on this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126829/395376).

Now, regarding your question. I would suggest that If you know someone whom you think can be active on this queue, you can be generous and place a bounty on one of their questions/answers, helping them reach the reputation threshold faster. There's a similar question [here](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4071/94498).

However, your right about needing more users to participate in clearing the review queues. I myself used to review as much as possible every day, before becoming a mod. Now I can't do the same because a moderator's vote is effective immediately, meaning that if a mod casts a close vote it will close the question instantly no matter how many votes are already cast. This makes it harder for mods to participate, especially now that we are trying to make the plugin questions of-topic.